# Equivalent characterizations of submanifolds locally

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

Let $N$ be a manifold. Let $S\subseteq N$. Show that $S$ is an embedded submanifold if and only if for each $p\in S$ there exists an open set $U$ in $N$ about $p$ and a smooth submersion $\varphi:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $U\cap S = \varphi^{-1}(0)$.

My attempt:

If $S$ is embedded submanifold, for $p\in S$ choose a chart $(U,x^1,...,x^n)$ in $N$ about $p$ such that $U\cap S$ is defined by the vanishing of $x^{1},...,x^k$. Hence set $\varphi:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ by $\varphi=(x^1,...,x^k)$. Then, $\varphi$ is the desired submersion.

Conversely, if $p\in S$ then take $\varphi$ as in the assumption.Hence $U\cap S$ is an emebdded submanifold in $U$ and thus $S$ is an embedded submanifold in $N$.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: well, you seem to be skipping over a lot of steps, but I guess the level of detail depends on what you're already allowed to assume. Particularly in the converse implication, you seem to already invoke the regular-value theorem, which is a consequence of the inverse/implicit function theorem. Also, the statement of the theorem isn't precise enough, it should be "*if and only if for every $p\in S$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $N$...*"

Comment: To elaborate on what @peek-a-boo said, you have to justify your assertions. In particular,, you say "choose a chart...such that...defined by the vanishing...". How do you know such a chart exists?

Comment: @Deane That's the definition of a (embedded) submanifold

Comment: @peek-a-boo for the converse, since $U\cap S$ is embedded in $U$, there exists a chart $(V,\phi = y^1,...,y^n)$ in $U$ such that $V\cap U \cap S$ is defined by the vanishing of some of the $y^i$. So $(V\cap U,\phi|_{V\cap U})$ is the desired chart in  $N$.

Comment: I mean $\phi$ being a submersion implying that $U\cap S$ is an embedded submanifold of $U$ (in the sense of the slice-chart condition) is the non-trivial part. This requires the IFT... but if you're taking this statement for granted, then sure the equivalence is almost trivial as you wrote.

Comment: @peek-a-boo ah I see. Yes, that part is due to the regular value theorem